# Retrofit with special chars at url

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

In my current project, I have some issues about the " and "=" symbols at URL.

http://mysampledomain.com/login?q='userlogin'="sample"

I have tried everything. "@Path" doesn't work and when I try "@Query" the characters "=" and ' " ' are changed to ASCII and It doesn't work.

http://mysampledomain.com/login?q%3D%userlogin%27=%22sample%22

How could I make this kind of requests?

Thank you!

Comment: There are some conventions you should respect. You final url should be in this form: `http://mysampledomain.com/login?userlogin=sample&param2=value2` (you can add or remove params per your needs)

Comment: you want to make a GET request through Retrofit ?

Comment: Yes, I know, but the back end was developed in that way and it cannot be changed. Is there any way to make retrofit works with these services?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution.

for anyone that it could help, I have used the @Url annotation like this:

```
@GET
Call<ApiResponseModel> getUserDetails(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Url String fullUrl);
```

Thanks for all the people that have reply my question :)

Comment: Then you are passing the complete URL in the above method

Answer (score 2):

Normally parameters through url are passed in different manner. In your case it would be:

http://mysampledomain.com/login?userlogin=sample&otherVariable=otherValue

Without ' ' characters usually.

For example I use node.js so it would be like:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
 var userLogin = req.query.userLogin;
 var otherVariable = req.query.otherVariable;

 // Do whatever you want.
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know that almost all services doesn't work with this pattern, but I have to make my application work with this kind of services. :(

Answer (score 1):

Use this approach

```
public static final String BASE_URL + "http://mysampledomain.com/";

public interface RetrofitClient{

     @GET("login")
     Call<String> login(@QueryMap Map<String, String> map);

}
```

to call this

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("userlogin", "sample");
map.put("param2", "param2");

OkHttpClient.Builder okBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setLenient()
    .create();

Retrofit  r = new Retrofit.Builder()
       .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
       .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
       .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
       .client(okBuilder.build())
       .build();

r.create(RetrofitClient.class).login(map).enqueue(this);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your api url if your api like

```
http://mysampledomain.com/login?userlogin=sample&otherVariable=otherValue
```

then

```
  @GET("login")
  Observable<LoginResponse> getUserProductViewed(@Query("userlogin") String userlogin,@Query("otherVariable")String otherVariable);
```

and Base URL like :

```
public static String BASE_URL = "http://mysampledomain.com/";
```

Comment: The problem is that the URL needs quote and equal symbol like this:

http://mysampledomain.com/login?q='userlogin'="sample"

My API needs that pattern and I am not able to resolve it.

Comment: It is not working.